# MongoDB removed collback from its driver, help solve the problem

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, postman

How can I fix this code so that it works correctly? If you enter a post id, it should be deleted.

I tried adding `promises`, `async`/`await` - didn't help. In Postman I entered everything correctly (tokens, links, etc.), the same error:

> Cannot DELETE /posts/(id)

```js
export const remove = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const postId = req.params.id;
    PostModel.findOneAndDelete({
        _id: postId,
      },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Failed to delete post",
          });
        }
        if (!doc) {
          return res.status(404).json({
            message: "Post was not found",
          });
        }
        res.json({
          success: true,
        });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Failed to get the posts",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: The error seems like an API error, not the mongoose or mongodb driver error. Can you please attach the code of defining API ?

Comment: Excuse me, the error was in the router.